# Why $p$ factor in $p \log p$ in the entropy formula?

Tags: entropy

[It is explained that we have log for additivity of information](http://umdberg.pbworks.com/w/page/49691685/Why%20entropy%20is%20logarithmic) in the entropy formula. But, why is the $p$ factor? It is redundant, since we already have it in the $\log p$!

Comment: For a random variable $X$ having support $\{x_1,\dots x_n\}$ with probabilities $\{p_1,\dots p_n\}$, the amount of information (in bits) you gain from a specific realisation of $X$, i.e. $X=x_i$, is given by $\log_2(1/p_i)$. The average amount of information you gain from $X$, i.e. the entropy of $X$, is given by:

$$\mathbb{E}[\log_2(1/p_i)]=\sum_{j=1}^n p_j\log_2(1/p_j)=:H(X).$$

Does this help at all?

Answer (score 3):

From Shannon's original paper ["A Mathematical Theory of Communication", *The Bell System Technical Journal*, Vol. 27, pp. 379–423, 623–656, July, October, 1948].

> If there is such a measure, say $H(p_1,p_2,...,p_n)$ , it is reasonable to require of it the following properties:
>
> 1. $H$ should be continuous in $p_i$
> 2. If all the $p_i$ are equal, $p_i = 1/n$ , then $H$ should be a monotonic increasing function of $n$. With equally likely events there is more choice, or uncertainty, when there are more possible events.
> 3. If a choice be broken down into two successive choices, the original $H$ should be the weighted sum of the individual values of $H$.

Basically requirement (3) entails the first $p$. Moverover, it can be shown that the form $H(\{p_i\}_{i=1,...n})=-\sum_i p_i \log p_i$ is the only one that satisfies the above 3 propositions.

Hope it helps.